# How to get all children nodes using $graphLookup of MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this data as below in a collection of MongoDB.

```
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "Dev" }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "Eliot", "parentId" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "Ron", "parentId" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 4, "name" : "Andrew", "parentId" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 5, "name" : "Asya", "parentId" : 3 }
{ "_id" : 6, "name" : "Dan", "parentId" : 4 }
```

And I can use "$graphLookup" to get children and parents.

```
db.xmantree.aggregate( [
   {
      name: "Eliot"
   },
   {
      $graphLookup: {
          from: 'xmantree',
          startWith: '$_id',
          connectFromField: 'parentId',
          connectToField: 'parentId',
          as: 'children'
       }
   },
  {
      $graphLookup: {
          from: 'xmantree',
          startWith: '$parentId',
          connectFromField: 'parentId',
          connectToField: '_id',
          as: 'parents'
       }
   }
] )
```

The result is this.

```
{
    _id:2,
    name: "Eliot",
    parentId: 1,
    children: [
        {
            _id: 3,
            name: "Ron",
            parentId: 2,
        },
        {
            _id: 4,
            name: "Andrew",
            parentId: 2,
        },
    ],
    parents: [
        {
            _id: 1,
            name: "Dev"
        }
    ]
}
```

But Each of Ron and Andrew has more children in this case. So I want to get this recursively by one query of aggregate. 
For example, this kind of result.

```
{
    _id:2,
    name: "Eliot",
    parentId: 1,
    children: [
        {
            _id: 3,
            name: "Ron",
            parentId: 2,
            children: [...] // <- I want to get this.
        },
        {
            _id: 4,
            name: "Andrew",
            parentId: 2,
            children: [...] // <- I want to get this.
        },
    ],
    parents: [
        {
            _id: 1,
            name: "Dev"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is my goal possible in MongoDB?

Comment: Is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jlfGd9zqFBo) what you are looking for? As shown, it is possible to get all children nodes in a single array, however I think you need to know the levels of recursion to get the layered form as you expected.

Comment: @ray Thank you. I think I can use your solution to add depth level in raw data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set your `$graphLookup` like this to get an array of all children nodes:

```js
{
    $graphLookup: {
      from: "xmantree",
      startWith: "$_id",
      connectFromField: "_id",
      connectToField: "parentId",
      as: "children"
    }
  }
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jlfGd9zqFBo) for your reference.

However, for your expected layered form of output, you will need to know the recursion level. If you have the information, you can do something like below:

```js
db.xmantree.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      name: "Eliot"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "xmantree",
      let: {
        parentId: "$_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$$parentId",
                "$parentId"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$lookup": {
            "from": "xmantree",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "parentId",
            "as": "children"
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "children"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7Mw2sCP7zDB) for your reference.